# Using ramda to modify data in array

Tags: ramda.js

Input:

```
[
  {
    temp: "24",
    date: "2019-10-16T11:00:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

Output:

```
[[new date("2019-10-16T11:00:00.000Z").getTime(), 24]]
```

Got some annoying mutability problems if I do it in vanilla javascript.

Good case to use ramda.

Something like:

```
const convertFunc = ...
const convertArr = R.map(convertFunc)


const result = convertArr(arr);
```

I'm stuck. Any ideas what Ramda functions to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure Ramda would add anything substantial. Especially if you can use parameter destructuring:

```
map(({temp, date}) => [new Date(date).getTime(), temp],
  [{ temp: "24",
     date: "2019-10-16T11:00:00.000Z"}]);
//=> [[1571223600000, "24"]]
```

Comment: And there's no chance of data mutate?

Comment: There's no mutation going on in the snippet I provided.

Comment: ... and of course, for the requested function, you could just write `const convertArr = R.map(({temp, date}) => [new Date(date).getTime(), temp])`

Answer (score 1):

You can map the array of objects, and use `R.evolve` to convert the date string to time via `Date.parse()`, and then get the `R.props` to convert to an array of arrays.

```js
const { map, pipe, evolve, identity, props } = R

const fn = map(pipe(
  evolve({ temp: identity, date: Date.parse }),
  props(['date', 'temp'])
))

const data = [{temp: "24",date: "2019-10-16T11:00:00.000Z"}]

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```